# Updated Android app after 2 years, cannot get it to appear on store

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, google-play, release

I know this has been discussed a lot on here, and I have looked at all those posts and potential solutions already. I have an app that has been on the store for 4 years. I stopped updating it about 2 years ago and just now decided to completely re-write the app and update it.

Well, I have done that and yet for some reason I cannot get it to show up on my phone as an update. I have checked that my phone can run the target SDK (which is 26, or Oreo 8.0). My phones Android version is 8.0 so it should recognize it, not to mention that I have installed the apk manually on my phone and it works fine.

The published app has been "live" since 10:17 this morning (almost 12 hours ago). I have confirmed that the android-version level is greater than the previous one, and have also tried clearing my phones app store cache, etc, many times to get it to appear on the store but I keep getting the 2 year old version of the app.

Anyone know what could be going on here? I have also tried releasing it on the beta tracks and internal test tracks, but I also cannot get it to update on my phone with those methods either. No matter what I get the 2 year old version of the app from the play store.

The app is built with Ionic 4 and Cordova version 7.0.0 if that matters, and I have signed the release apk with the same key I have used since the start of this app 4 years ago.

When I was doing this 2 years ago I remember being able to get the published updated app in around 30 min to an hour, so this is very strange to me and I feel like I have to have missed something.

Comment: The speed with which updates show up in the play store on different devices is pretty variable, I've found. I wouldn't be surprised if it just took another 12 hours

Comment: @Kai it has been another 12 hours and still no update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. It turned out that my old app version, even though it started with a 2 and my new one started with a 3, was a bigger NUMBER. So even though the app version is higher, if the generated number is higher it still sees the highest number as the latest version.